# Style div elements to ignore baseline while remaining in a grid

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I have a problem with css/scss. It's difficult to explain, but I will do my best. Attaching images to better communicate what I'm trying to say.

I have a container div which contains five child divs:
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBctk.png)

These child divs contain FAQ questions that reveal the answer when the user clicks on a question. Hence, the div will grow vertically. The mockup I have received shows the tapped answer opening and "pushing" the below div downwards, while all other divs remain in place:
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTJ98.png)

So, my question is, how do I go about this? I have tried making the parent div a flexbox, table and grid, but the problem still stands. I have also tried to make the child divs into floats, but that pushes the element to the side rather than downwards.

I picture placing the items in columns, which I could do if the divs were hardcoded, but they are created dynamically in a for loop:

```html
@foreach (var category in Model.Content.Children().Where(x => x.IsVisible() && x.DocumentTypeAlias == "fAQSamling"))
    {
        <div class="faq-main-card question">
            <div class="faq-header">
                <object type="image/svg+xml" data="--"></object>
                <h3 class="heading-24">@category.Name</h3>
            </div>
                @foreach (var question in category.Children().Where(x => x.IsVisible() && x.DocumentTypeAlias == "faqItem"))
                {
                    <div class="question">
                        <h4 class="faq-question-title" title="Klicka för att visa svaret på frågan.">
                            @(question.HasValue("faqQuestion") ? question.GetPropertyValue("faqQuestion") : question.Name)
                            <object type="image/svg+xml" data="--"></object>
                        </h4>
                        <div>
                            @question.GetPropertyValue("fAQAnswer")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
        </div>
    }
```

I hope I have explained properly. Please ask me to clarify if I need to. If it is relevant to the solution, the "answers" are set to height 0 with overflow hidden when closed, and when opened they're set to height 'auto'. The opening function is written in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello instead of using flex i have used bootstrap row and column to do the task but the example cannot be used in all type of situations.

```css
.hello{
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: salmon;
  margin: 30px;
}
.hello h1{
  text-align: center;
}
.hello:hover{
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0 ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="hello"><h1>asa</h1> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa corrupti eos assumenda voluptatibus voluptatum tenetur quae dolorum soluta recusandae natus blanditiis omnis in, nulla commodi saepe provident vel laboriosam architecto? Modi omnis dolor sint, corrupti ipsum possimus! Repellat temporibus suscipit aspernatur, nulla illum dolorem facere magnam. Nam necessitatibus reprehenderit nisi eius cumque. Eius ex quaerat perspiciatis fugit eum, necessitatibus deleniti excepturi dolor, omnis saepe quia aliquam accusantium amet incidunt repudiandae, asperiores velit porro aspernatur sint? Possimus dolorum consequuntur provident dolorem praesentium sint ea et sequi nisi. Incidunt temporibus illo commodi voluptate ex molestias necessitatibus inventore at facilis dolore, consequatur officiis adipisci vel, magni impedit suscipit itaque, mollitia maxime optio qui voluptatem sequi! Omnis error adipisci veniam animi numquam tenetur quam minus dolorem ex sit perferendis facere nisi, ratione aut excepturi quae eos officiis laboriosam! Debitis doloribus maiores sit, voluptatem amet optio distinctio laboriosam a porro, qui corporis. Fuga, quam dignissimos.</div>
      <div class="hello"><h1>asfa</h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa corrupti eos assumenda voluptatibus voluptatum tenetur quae dolorum soluta recusandae natus blanditiis omnis in, nulla commodi saepe provident vel laboriosam architecto? Modi omnis dolor sint, corrupti ipsum possimus! Repellat temporibus suscipit aspernatur, nulla illum dolorem facere magnam. Nam necessitatibus reprehenderit nisi eius cumque. Eius ex quaerat perspiciatis fugit eum, necessitatibus deleniti excepturi dolor, omnis saepe quia aliquam accusantium amet incidunt repudiandae, asperiores velit porro aspernatur sint? Possimus dolorum consequuntur provident dolorem praesentium sint ea et sequi nisi. Incidunt temporibus illo commodi voluptate ex molestias necessitatibus inventore at facilis dolore, consequatur officiis adipisci vel, magni impedit suscipit itaque, mollitia maxime optio qui voluptatem sequi! Omnis error adipisci veniam animi numquam tenetur quam minus dolorem ex sit perferendis facere nisi, ratione aut excepturi quae eos officiis laboriosam! Debitis doloribus maiores sit, voluptatem amet optio distinctio laboriosam a porro, qui corporis. Fuga, quam dignissimos.</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="hello"><h1>asfs</h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa corrupti eos assumenda voluptatibus voluptatum tenetur quae dolorum soluta recusandae natus blanditiis omnis in, nulla commodi saepe provident vel laboriosam architecto? Modi omnis dolor sint, corrupti ipsum possimus! Repellat temporibus suscipit aspernatur, nulla illum dolorem facere magnam. Nam necessitatibus reprehenderit nisi eius cumque. Eius ex quaerat perspiciatis fugit eum, necessitatibus deleniti excepturi dolor, omnis saepe quia aliquam accusantium amet incidunt repudiandae, asperiores velit porro aspernatur sint? Possimus dolorum consequuntur provident dolorem praesentium sint ea et sequi nisi. Incidunt temporibus illo commodi voluptate ex molestias necessitatibus inventore at facilis dolore, consequatur officiis adipisci vel, magni impedit suscipit itaque, mollitia maxime optio qui voluptatem sequi! Omnis error adipisci veniam animi numquam tenetur quam minus dolorem ex sit perferendis facere nisi, ratione aut excepturi quae eos officiis laboriosam! Debitis doloribus maiores sit, voluptatem amet optio distinctio laboriosam a porro, qui corporis. Fuga, quam dignissimos.</div>
      <div class="hello"><h1>asfa</h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa corrupti eos assumenda voluptatibus voluptatum tenetur quae dolorum soluta recusandae natus blanditiis omnis in, nulla commodi saepe provident vel laboriosam architecto? Modi omnis dolor sint, corrupti ipsum possimus! Repellat temporibus suscipit aspernatur, nulla illum dolorem facere magnam. Nam necessitatibus reprehenderit nisi eius cumque. Eius ex quaerat perspiciatis fugit eum, necessitatibus deleniti excepturi dolor, omnis saepe quia aliquam accusantium amet incidunt repudiandae, asperiores velit porro aspernatur sint? Possimus dolorum consequuntur provident dolorem praesentium sint ea et sequi nisi. Incidunt temporibus illo commodi voluptate ex molestias necessitatibus inventore at facilis dolore, consequatur officiis adipisci vel, magni impedit suscipit itaque, mollitia maxime optio qui voluptatem sequi! Omnis error adipisci veniam animi numquam tenetur quam minus dolorem ex sit perferendis facere nisi, ratione aut excepturi quae eos officiis laboriosam! Debitis doloribus maiores sit, voluptatem amet optio distinctio laboriosam a porro, qui corporis. Fuga, quam dignissimos.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="hello"><h1>asfa</h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa corrupti eos assumenda voluptatibus voluptatum tenetur quae dolorum soluta recusandae natus blanditiis omnis in, nulla commodi saepe provident vel laboriosam architecto? Modi omnis dolor sint, corrupti ipsum possimus! Repellat temporibus suscipit aspernatur, nulla illum dolorem facere magnam. Nam necessitatibus reprehenderit nisi eius cumque. Eius ex quaerat perspiciatis fugit eum, necessitatibus deleniti excepturi dolor, omnis saepe quia aliquam accusantium amet incidunt repudiandae, asperiores velit porro aspernatur sint? Possimus dolorum consequuntur provident dolorem praesentium sint ea et sequi nisi. Incidunt temporibus illo commodi voluptate ex molestias necessitatibus inventore at facilis dolore, consequatur officiis adipisci vel, magni impedit suscipit itaque, mollitia maxime optio qui voluptatem sequi! Omnis error adipisci veniam animi numquam tenetur quam minus dolorem ex sit perferendis facere nisi, ratione aut excepturi quae eos officiis laboriosam! Debitis doloribus maiores sit, voluptatem amet optio distinctio laboriosam a porro, qui corporis. Fuga, quam dignissimos.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This Raw code requires quite a lot of more editing to be put in use.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I did something like that, had to hardcode the columns but as long as the designer is happy ;) Have a good day!